# Does anybody know why contextgarden.net is down?

Tags: context

Since a few days contextgarden.net as well as the context mailing list is not available and seems to be down.

Does anyone know what's going on there?

Comment: I've heard rumors about broken hardware that needs to be replaced, but I really do now know if that is what is going on or how long it will be down.

Comment: https://mailman.ntg.nl/archives/list/ntg-context@ntg.nl/message/2U2IJCHCQV2V36XTLRJUOOQADA463EBE/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's only temporally relevant in nature (and more suitable for the ConTeXt mailing list).

Comment: @Dava Jarvis: The mailing list was also down so this was the best place to ask.